# Sidekiq enqueues job in the past

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

- We have two servers A and B
- When we enqueue Active Jobs, Server A shows that a job has been created a minute ago in the Sidekiq web interface, but **Server B shows that the job has been created 3 hours ago.**
- The same is true for

```
set(wait: 10.hours).perform_later(object_id) 
=> Server A in Sidekiq Web UI: In 10 hours
=> Server B in Sidekiq Web UI: In 7 hours
```

- Server A and B both return the same date and /etc/timezone

```
$ date
Mo 9. Aug 15:32:14 CEST 2021 
$ cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Berlin
```

**We have a test job to reproduce the problem:**

```
  4 class TimeTestJob < ApplicationJob
  5   queue_as :default
  6
  7   def perform(time)
  8     puts "Time in Sidekiq: #{Time.now.to_s}"
  9     puts "DateTime in Sidekiq: #{DateTime.now.to_s}"
 10     puts "time args: #{time.to_s}"
 11     ...
 16   end
 17
 18 end
```

**The output is identical on both servers**

```
TimeTestJob.perform_now(Time.now.to_s)
Performing TimeTestJob (Job ID: b542c55d-7957-48db-83b8-7d0620accb6f) from Sidekiq(default) enqueued at with arguments: "2021-08-09 15:32:14 +0200"

Time in Sidekiq: 2021-08-09 15:32:14 +0200
DateTime in Sidekiq: 2021-08-09T15:32:14+02:00
time args: 2021-08-09 15:32:14 +0200

Enqueued TimeTestJob (Job ID: d3d9b7e7-2d97-4700-9c93-9e61f9fbeae5) to Sidekiq(default) at 2021-08-09 23:33:14 UTC with arguments: "2021-08-09 15:32:14 +0200"
...
```

Any ideas what could be the issue for the time offset on Server B?

Comment: Just to understand the setup a bit more... There a 2 `rails s` running with each there own route to sidekiq dashboard and there is one sidekiq instance running and both of the rails servers use that instance?

Comment: Yes, those are two different machines entirely. Both run Debian 10 with the same provisioning. Running `Time.now.utc` on each rails console also gives the same output. The unix time in redis (sidekiq backend) is also identical. Weird...

Comment: I assume the testjob gets send from server A right? What happens if you send it from server B? Are the hours switched around or is it something like `10 hours` and `13 hours`?

Comment: We're still investigating, but it might have something todo with the fact that Sidekiq always uses the local system time of the computer. We have a Virtual Box environment and it seems that Time Zones are correct on the VM but not on the host itself, thus having a different time in Sidekiq.